# Display parent and child taxonomies in separate drop down select fields

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I've used a piece of code from another question here but my second select field did not changed accordingly. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Below is my code:

My php functions:

```
function products_selection()
{
    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'seller',
      'taxonomy'    => 'category',
      'hide_empty'  => 0,
      'exclude'     => 1,1078,1079
    );
    $products = get_categories( $args );

    if ( $products ) {
    echo '<select id="products-select">';
      echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Προϊόντα</span></option>';

      foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<option class="product-name" id="'. $product->term_id .'">'. $product->name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }
}

function nomoi()
{
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'seller',
    'taxonomy'  => 'nomos',
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
    'parent'    => 0
    );

  $categories = get_categories( $args );

  if ( $categories ) {
    // print_r($categories);
    echo '<select id="nomoi-select">';
      echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Νομοί</span></option>';

      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $id = $category->term_id;
        $name = $category->name;
        $taxonomy = $category->taxonomy;
        echo '<option class="nomos" id="'. $id .'">'. $name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }
  // implement_ajax();
  $args = array(
      'order_by' => 'name',
      'hide_empty' => 0,
      'depth' => 1,
      'exclude' => 1,
      'taxonomy' => 'nomos',
      'name' => 'main_cat',
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'show_option_none' => 'Νομοί',
      'selected' => 0
    );
  wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
   // wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=0&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Νομοί&name=main_cat&taxonomy=nomos');
  ?><select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" disabled="disabled"></select><?php
}

function towns()
{
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'nomos',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 1,
    );
  $cats = get_categories( $args );
  echo '<select id="town-select">';
    echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Πόλεις</span></option>';
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
      $cat_name = $cat->name;
      $id = $cat->cat_ID;
      echo '<option class="town" id="'. $id .'">'. $cat_name .'</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';
}

function my_ajax() {

if(isset($_POST['main_catid']))
    {
    $categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
      foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
        $option .= $cat->cat_name;
        $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
        $option .= '</option>';
      }
      echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Πόλεις</option>'.$option;
    die();
    } // end if
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax', 'my_ajax');//for users that are not logged in.
```

My jQuery function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $('#main_cat').change(function() {
    var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();

      // call ajax
      $("#sub_cat").empty();
      $.ajax
      (
          {
              url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              type:'POST',
              data:'action=my_ajax&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

              success:function(results)
              {
                  //  alert(results);
                  $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
                  $("#sub_cat").append(results);
              }
          }
      );
  });
});
```

And finally my enqueue script function:

```
function my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'header-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/headerform.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```